# cannot change input property after overriding same property by child component reference - @ViewChild()

Tags: angular, viewchild

i am trying to toggle the visibility of child components from parent component by @ViewChild. 
i am setting `visiblity` of both child component as true from the `allComponentVisibility=true` of parent.

And on some event, I set the `allComponentVisibility=false` and change the `visiblity=true` of particular component through **@viewchild**.

But `visiblity` is not changing when i set `allComponentVisibility=false` in _**AppComponent.ts**

#### First Child Component

```
export class RecipesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('setRecipeVisibility') visibility: boolean;  
}
```

#### Second Child Component

```
export class ShoppingListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('setShoppingListVisiblity') visibility : boolean;
}
```

#### Parent Template File

```
<app-header 
  (onRecipeEventFired)="setRecipeVisible()" 
  (onshoppingListEventFired)="setShoppingListVisible()">
</app-header>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <app-recipes 
        [setRecipeVisibility]="allComponentVisibility" 
        #recipeReference>
      </app-recipes>
      <app-shopping-list 
        [setShoppingListVisiblity]="allComponentVisibility" 
        #shoppingListReference>
      </app-shopping-list>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### parent Typescript File

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(RecipesComponent) recipeReference: RecipesComponent;
  @ViewChild(ShoppingListComponent) shoppingListReference: ShoppingListComponent;

  allComponentVisibility = true;

  setRecipeVisible(){
    this.allComponentVisibility = false;
    this.recipeReference.visibility=true;
  }

  setShoppingListVisible(){
    this.allComponentVisibility = false;
    this.shoppingListReference.visibility=true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make an INPUT it takes as reference the variable you are passing
So basicly what are you doing is making the children's variables be referenced to allComponentVisibility.

So the children's value will always be the same as allComponentVisibility.
Changing the parent or any of the child, will change the same reference.

You should try to think of some other control variables to know which component should be visible, you could separate the variables for example.